# spring boot find by field search specification

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, specifications

My problem is I can search from database. But I did searching by using `findAll` of `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. But, I want to do searching by using `findById` and pass my `specification`, `pageable` and `id` to it return `page`. But it is not working.

Here is my `controller`:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/search")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> allAccountRightService(
                    @RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search,
                    @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
                    @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size,
                    @RequestParam(value = "order", required = false) String order,
                    @RequestParam(value = "orderBy", required = false) String orderBy) {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO("accountRightService List", accountRightService.search(search, page, size, order, orderBy));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

and here is my `service impl` method:

public Map<PageInformation, List<AccountRightDTO>> search(String search, Integer page, Integer size, String order,
            String orderBy) {
        Map<PageInformation, List<AccountRightDTO>> accountRightList = new HashMap<>();

        PageInformation pageInfo = new PageInformation();

        if (order == null || order.isEmpty())
            order = "DESC";

        if (orderBy == null || orderBy.isEmpty())
            orderBy = "createdAt";


        Pageable pageable = CommonUtil.createPageRequest(page, size, order, orderBy);

        Specification<AccountRight> spec = CommonUtil.buildSearchSpecification(search);
        //Page<AccountRight> accountRightPage = accountRightRepository.findAllByRightByAppointment(CommonUtil.getAppointment().getAppointmentID(), spec, pageable);
        Page<AccountRight> accountRightPage = accountRightRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
        List<AccountRight> accountRights = accountRightPage.getContent();

        List<AccountRightDTO> accountRightDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        accountRightDTOs = accountRights.stream().map(accountRight -> {
            AccountRightDTO accountRightDTO = new AccountRightDTO();
            AppointmentDTO rightToAppointmentDTO = new AppointmentDTO();
            AppointmentDTO rightByAppointmentDTO = new AppointmentDTO();

            BeanUtils.copyProperties(accountRight, accountRightDTO, "accountRightID");

            accountRightDTO.setAccountRightID(Long.toString(accountRight.getAccountRightID()));


            BeanUtils.copyProperties(accountRight.getRightToAppointment(), rightToAppointmentDTO, "appointmentID");
            rightToAppointmentDTO.setAppointmentID(Long.toString(accountRight.getRightToAppointment().getAppointmentID()));

            BeanUtils.copyProperties(accountRight.getRightByAppointment(), rightByAppointmentDTO, "appointmentID");
            rightByAppointmentDTO.setAppointmentID(Long.toString(accountRight.getRightToAppointment().getAppointmentID()));

            accountRightDTO.setRightByAppointment(rightByAppointmentDTO);
            accountRightDTO.setRightToAppointment(rightToAppointmentDTO);

            return accountRightDTO;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        pageInfo.setSize(accountRightPage.getSize());
        pageInfo.setTotalElements(accountRightPage.getTotalElements());
        pageInfo.setTotalPages(accountRightPage.getTotalPages());

        accountRightList.put(pageInfo, accountRightDTOs);
        return accountRightList;
    }
```

and this is my `buildsearchspecification` method

```
public static <T> Specification<T> buildSearchSpecification(String search) {

        SearchSpecificationsBuilder<T> builder = new SearchSpecificationsBuilder<T>();

        if (search != null && !search.isEmpty()) {
            String[] str = search.split(",");
            if (str != null) {
                for (String strTemp : str) {
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Punct}?)(.*)(:|!|<|>|~)(.*)(\\p{Punct}?),");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strTemp + ",");
                    while (matcher.find()) {
                        builder.with(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2),
                                SearchOperation.getSimpleOperation(matcher.group(3).toCharArray()[0]),
                                matcher.group(4));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Specification<T> spec = builder.build();
        return spec;
    }
```

and here is my `findAllByRightByAppointment` repository method

```
@Query("select account from AccountRight account where account.rightByAppointment.appointmentID=?1")
    Page<AccountRight> findAllByRightByAppointment(Long appointmentID, @Nullable Specification<AccountRight> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

If I use `findAll` method than searching will work otherwise by using my custom method `pagination` works without `searching`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by using `Specification.Where(your_specification).and(your_search_specification).`

here is my updated code now:

```
Specification<AccountRight> searchSpec = CommonUtil.buildSearchSpecification(search); //this specification needs my search string.
        SearchSpecification<AccountRight> rightByAppointmentID = 
                  new SearchSpecification<AccountRight>(new SearchCriteria("rightByAppointment.appointmentID", SearchOperation.EQUALITY, CommonUtil.getAppointment().getAppointmentID())); //this specification accepts search criteria with key, operation and value.


        Page<AccountRight> accountRightPage = accountRightRepository.findAll(Specification.where(rightByAppointmentID).and(searchSpec), pageable); 

//here you will just tell findAll method to findAll entities where rightByAppointmentID is equal to
   //CommonUtil.getAppointment().getAppointmentID() and search query is searchSpec
```